# Meteor login redirect

Tags: redirect, meteor, authentication, iron-router

I try to redirect user to a different route as soon as user logs in using Iron Router. I read many answers and even the code below should work as many others' code did, but I do not know why it does not work :( Please help, I am struggling for so many hours!

`Meteor.loginWithPassword(login_email, login_password, function(err) {
            submit_button.button("reset");
            if (err)
            {
                pageSession.set("errorMessage", err.reason);
                return false;
            }
            Router.go('user.user_evaluations_received',{userId:Meteor.userId()});
        });`

Comment: Is `user.user_evaluations_received` the name of a route? Looks a bit odd for a route name. I use a similar login pattern with i-r and it works flawlessly.

Comment: yes, it is name of route ! I think I am the only one who can't make it work like that :(

Comment: Have you tried an unpunctuated route name, ex: "foo"?

Comment: Yes I did unpunctuate!

Comment: How exactly does it fail? Can you show your route definition?

Comment: I think I found a solution, just can you tell me if there is a way to save an userId from callback. I tried session.set(...) but it is unavailable outside .loginWithPassword() function.

Comment: `Meteor.userId()` will be the `_id` of the current logged-in user after login. You don't need a session variable to track it.